# How should the reactivity of 1-propanesulfonyl chloride be expected to compare to tosyl chloride for sulfonylation?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, reactivity

I've come across some scientific literature (e.g., https://doi.org/10.1021/jm400751p) that notably feature 1-propanesulfonyl chloride (PsCl) in the selective activation of hydroxy groups, such as a primary alcohol at the expense of a secondary one. Since tosyl chloride (TsCl) is so much more commonly used than structural homologues of mesyl chloride (MsCl) in general alcohol activation, this has prompted me to wonder: Starting from and explaining with organic chemistry concepts, how should the reactivity of PsCl for alcohol activation (or amino-group sulfonylation) be expected to compare to TsCl?

Obviously, like MsCl, PsCl has access to alpha-carbon protons (though at least somewhat less acidic due to the longer alkyl chain of EDGs), so sulfene intermediates would be expected to form in the case of a sufficiently strong base such as triethylamine or DIPEA. Then, generating less of a reactive sulfene intermediate at a given time (compared to MsCl, see https://doi.org/10.1021/jo981532p for reference) should favor PsCl's use in ensuring greater selectivity in sulfonylation (specifically, when one substrate site is more nucleophilic than another). From a structural perspective, I am inclined to think of PsCl as being TsCl minus the methyl group and the "bottom" (from a 2-D perspective) three C-atoms of TsCl's benzene ring (along with, of course, no C-C double bonds), so sterically-speaking PsCl's S-atom should be at-least-slightly more available for a nucleophilic attack (e.g., courtesy of a weaker base like pyridine). Though, from the electronics-perspective I'm not sure what impact TsCl's aromaticity would have on the S-atom's electrophilic character (charge delocalization perhaps leading to greater electrophilicity?). TsCl also naturally doesn't have an alpha-carbon with protons, which would seem to preclude its having an E1cB or E2-like reaction capacity.

Here is a paper (https://doi.org/10.1021/jo00821a030) in which one can see that the rate of secondary hydroxy group activation in anhydrous pyridine (serving as solvent, in addition to catalyzing hydroxy-group activation) clearly proceeded faster for PsCl than TsCl. Since pyridine would be catalyzing hydroxy-group activation through an SN2-like attack on the PsCl/TsCl S-atom, this would seem to indicate that steric factors play some role in PsCl being more reactive than TsCl.

Comment: In your first citation there is apparently no amine base present, which would preclude initial salt formation with PsCl or deprotonation, leaving direct displacement by $\ce{RCH2OH}$. Hence, a source of selectivity. I recall from the distant past that MsCl reacts by a different mechanism in the presence of pyridine vs. triethylamine. In the former case, salt formation occurs; In the latter case, sulfene formation occurs. Sorry, but I don't have a reference.

Comment: @user55119 For the 1st citation, see Scheme 4 on the 3rd page and particularly the 6th page (which is in the Experimental Section). 2,6-lutidine, a pyridine derivative with di-ortho-substituted -CH3 groups, was used as the base (i.e., nucleophilic catalyst). 100% yield for the di-propanesulfonate (as crude material) was attained.

Comment: I only looked at reagent "b" in scheme 4 that has no mention of 2,6-lutidine while the experimental section does. IMO, 2,6-lutidine is only going to act as a scavenger for generated HCl. Certainly too hindered for attack at sulfur and unlikely to deprotonate PsCl. This still consistent with my thoughts above.